# syntax highlighting using python in bookdown

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, syntax-highlighting, bookdown

I use a basic bookdown document/project with highlight theme pygments. Additionally I run python in my code chunks. In the produced pdf output, the syntax highlighting of the python code appears as desired

[image: pdf output]

However, looking on the html output, it differs from the pdf output

[image: html output]

as for example `import` is not printed in bold and green, the `print()` code is not printed in green. What is the reason for this problem and how could I change it? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @K J Thank you! However, is it possible to change to code highlighting in the gitbook (html version)? The printed pdf output can be adapted with e.g. `pandoc_args: --highlight-style=my.theme` and a custom theme my.theme. Unfortunately, this does not apply to the gitbook (html version) ...

Comment: Ok, I found the answer: for the gitbook (html version) one needs to select in my case in the _output.yml file `highlight: my.theme` under `bookdown::gitbook::`. For the printed version (e.g. pdf) one selects `pandoc_args: --highlight-style=my.theme` under `bookdown::pdf_book::`. Afterwards you can customize your theme template my.theme as you want and the appearance in the gitbook and  pdf will be the same! :)